# Histogram doesn't change after adjusting brightness

Tags: c#, image-processing, histogram

I have a form that can show the histogram of `picturebox.Image`. And then I added a brightness slider, and it's working. But after I adjust the brightness of the image, the histogram is not changing. How can I change a histogram based on image brightness?

What I tried is re-execute the histogram button, and it's still not changing. The brightness and histogram is in a different class/form. Sorry, still newbie on image processing.

1. [Actual histogram chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LCMyC.jpg)
2. Here's after I re-execute histogram button. [Still same histogram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UDb53.jpg)

**Mainform.cs**

```
    Bitmap newBit; //initialize new Bitmap

    //Open the image with Dialogresult
     private void openImage_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
        OpenFileDialog img = new OpenFileDialog();

        if (img.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK) {
            pbOutput.Image = new Bitmap(img.FileName); //I take this image from picturebox
            newBit = new Bitmap(img.FileName);
     }

    //for adjusting slider
    private void bBar_Scroll(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        brighText.Text = bScroll.Value.ToString();
        pbOutput.Image = adjustBrightness(newBit, bScroll.Value);
    }

    //brightness method (color matrix)
    public static Bitmap adjustBrightness(Bitmap Image, int value)
    {
        Bitmap tempBit = Image;

        float v = value / 255.0f;
        Bitmap newBit = new Bitmap(tempBit.Width, tempBit.Height);
        Graphics newGraphics = Graphics.FromImage(newBit);

        float[][] f = {
            new float[] {1, 0, 0, 0, 0},
            new float[] {0, 1, 0, 0, 0},
            new float[] {0, 0, 1, 0, 0},
            new float[] {0, 0, 0, 1, 0},
            new float[] {v, v, v, 1, 1}
        };

        ColorMatrix newMatrix = new ColorMatrix(f);
        ImageAttributes a = new ImageAttributes();
        a.SetColorMatrix(newMatrix);
        newGraphics.DrawImage(tempBit, new Rectangle(0, 0, tempBit.Width, tempBit.Height), 0, 0, tempBit.Width, tempBit.Height, GraphicsUnit.Pixel, a);
        return newBit;

    }
```

**Histogram.cs**

```
        public Histogram(Image image)
        {

        Bitmap b = new Bitmap(image);

        String[] seriesArray = { "Red", "Green", "Blue" };
        int[] pointsArray = { 1, 2, 3 };

        int[] histogram_r = new int[256];
        int[] histogram_g = new int[256];
        int[] histogram_b = new int[256];

        float max = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < b.Width; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < b.Height; j++) {
                int redValue = b.GetPixel(i, j).R;
                int greenValue = b.GetPixel(i, j).G;
                int blueValue = b.GetPixel(i, j).B;

                histogram_r[redValue]++;
                histogram_g[greenValue]++;
                histogram_b[blueValue]++;

                if (max < histogram_r[redValue])
                    max = histogram_r[redValue];

                if (max < histogram_g[greenValue])
                    max = histogram_g[greenValue];

                if (max < histogram_b[blueValue])
                    max = histogram_b[blueValue];

            }
        }

        histChart.Titles.Add("RGB Histogram");

        for (int j = 0; j < seriesArray.Length; j++) {
            Series series = histChart.Series.Add(seriesArray[j]);
            for (int i = 0; i < histogram_r.Length; i++) {
                if (j == 0) {
                    series.Points.Add(histogram_r[i]);
                }

                else if (j == 1) {
                    series.Points.Add(histogram_g[i]);
                }

                else {
                    series.Points.Add(histogram_b[i]);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You don't show what you pass to the `Histogram` function or when you call it.  The problem could be lurking there.

Comment: How can I pass the Histogram function?

Comment: you did not provide the code section that invokes Histogram(Image image). The problem lies there...  you're most likely creating the histogram from the same image twice

Comment: [Here's from MainForm.cs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HJuNg.jpg)
To render histogram [Here's from OptionsForm.cs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kklBw.jpg)

Comment: So `Histogram` is a `Form`, and each time you click `hist` on the `Options` form, you create and show a new `Histogram` form.  That's not a histogram _changing_ per se, it's _creating a new one_, and I expect that each time you click `hist` you will have to close the old `Histogram` form and look at the new `Histogram` form that just got created, given the way you have things set up right now.

Comment: Also, you should be editing your question to include new relevant information (like those code excerpts you added), as opposed to adding a link to that information in a comment. And definitely don't share code in image format.  Edit your question and add the code as text in the body of your question, formatted using the _code sample_ mechanism.